# BX-SLIDER not showing the content in popup window initially

Tags: javascript, html, css

BX-SLIDER not showing the content in popup window initially after resizing the window it works normal.

Comment: Add some code otherwise it's impossible for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to use the bx slider reload function. You can use it in your jQuery code after DOM ready:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({});
slider.reloadSlider();
```

edit: http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider